# [PHP][Mysql] Select and show simple

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
#GET from Mysql
$select = "SELECT content from content WHERE page = 'index';";
$result = mysql_query($select);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

#Show in diferent places in my page
<?PHP echo $row[0]; ?>
<?PHP echo $row[1]; ?>
```

I'm using this code above, the problem is:
It's showing only the first result. What did I wrong?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_row  the function fetches a **SINGLE** row of data.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: It's for a client. I really have to do this way or I will have to do using prepared statements in all his pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$select = "SELECT content from content WHERE page = 'index';";
$result = mysql_query($select);

//$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
// mysql_fetch_row() fetches ONLY ONE ROW

// If you want to fetch them all, yes, you must use a loop.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
// So do this, get all the rows, and then you can use them in different places in your page

// Show in diferent places in your page
<?PHP echo $rows[0][0]; ?>
<?PHP echo $rows[1][0]; ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's better to do this in a for loop - that way it will get all the results each time, rather than hardcoding for a scenario with just two results, etc.

```
<?php
$select = "SELECT content from content WHERE page = 'index';";
$result = mysql_query($select);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['content']; // associative array with strings for keys
}
?>
```

Also, you should be using `mysqli` for security reasons.

Comment: Cannot I use it without using loop? The echos are in diferent parts of the page

Comment: You can run the query in one place and put the print loop wherever you need it so long as the variable is in scope.